# Kyocera m5521cdn scanner is busy

Tags: printer, network-printer, scanner

I have been using Kyocera Print Center to scan over LAN, and it has worked perfectly in the past. However, recently, I encounter an error message that says, "a problem occurred during scanning." This message suggests that the scanner is busy. Strangely, when I use the Android app on my phone or the NAPS2 desktop application with a TWAIN driver, the scanning process works without any issues.

I am using Kyocera m5521cdn  and the latest version of Kyocera Print Center. I have also tried

How can I resolve this problem and get Kyocera Print Center to scan normally over LAN again?

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Kyocera ECOSYS M6535cidn .
After last friday, the scanner just stopped working on all PCs. The message i was gettings from all test was : Scanner is busy. I applied all solutions around the web but nothing worked.
Until today i fixed it casually by making a mess with the drivers and was able to replicate it with the next PCs.

Perhaps these steps might help you too :

- Installed twains drivers of the actual model : Scanner_Ecosys_M-P6x3xcdn.This driver stopped working and gave error
  " Scanner is busy " .
- Installed twains drivers of another model :
  TWAINScannerDriver_v2.0.8106. This model worked before but scanned
  without colors.
- Installed naps2-7.1.2-win.exe
- Control Panel - Twain 32Bit - Add Scanner model with its IP.
- Go to Naps2 and add the profile with this scanner.
- Scan with NativeUI and select Image - Color on its native IU which now is different from the original one i had before it stopped
  working.

Hope it helps.

Comment: the problem was in the kyocera print center app i used naps2 with TWAIN DRIVER  and there is also kyocera quick scan tool it works fine and now they have updated the kyocera print center app it is back to normal thanks for your help